# Why does boost::filesystem is_directory return different results when run as a Windows Service?

Tags: windows, boost, windows-services, boost-filesystem

I have some code that iterates through files in a directory and does useful things with the non-directory files, like so:

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
for (bfs::directory_iterator iterDir(m_inPath); 
     bContinue && iterDir!=bfs::directory_iterator(); iterDir++)
{
    std::string filename = iterDir->path().filename().string();
    boost::to_lower(filename);

    if (!bfs::is_directory(*iterDir) && Condition2(filename)) {
        std::ifstream ifFile(iterDir->path().string().c_str());
        DoUsefulThings(iterDir());
    }
}
```

This works fine in my unit tests, but when I run the full program as a service, my test directories (seemingly erroneously) get past the `!bfs::is_directory` check and `DoUsefulThings`'s `ifstream.good()` check fails, with an errno of 13.

I tried changing `!bfs::is_directory` to `bfs::is_regular_file` (thinking that maybe there was a system condition causing it to be something else), but I got the same results.  The `is_regular_file` condition fails on the directory in my unit test but passes when run as a service.

I also added a try/catch around my if statement to see if it was throwing an exception and verified that it wasn't (probably could use one anyway, but didn't help with this).

I considered that the problem could be related to the service's permissions level, so I changed the properties of the service to log on as the same account that I use to log in to that system.  Same result.  I've dabbled with PerformanceMonitor some as well to try to get some clues there, but I haven't gleaned much from it yet.

Can someone suggest why this might be happening?  Errno=13 == "permission denied", right?  Is there an additional check I need to perform before calling is_directory?

I'm using Windows XP, Visual Studio 2008/C++, version 1.44 of the Boost library, and version 3 of filesystem.

ETA: I added the following to test the directory manually (the direction of the slash marks didn't make a difference), and is_regular_file behaves as expected:

```
std::string strDir = "D:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/Dir5\\Dir6";
if (bfs::is_regular_file(strDir))
    LOG("It's a regular file"); //This does not get executed
else
    LOG("Not a regular file");  //This does
```

I have log statements printing out both *iterDir and iterDir->path() and they both match the one I put in manually.  Does this rule out permissions issues?  Will continue testing, as this result doesn't really make sense to me yet.

Comment: permissions... I'm guessing the directory is not accessible/traversable

Comment: So what is the actual directory path? It might be UNC path inaccessible to service, or it could be remote share mapped to a drive, with mapping invisible for the service. The path will give you a hint why service does not see it.

Comment: You can also try running service under user's credentials, as opposed to default  `LocalService`.

Comment: @sehe: I tried manually setting the permissions on the directory to allow "Everyone" full access.  I also tried adding another directory in the same location (thinking maybe the other one got mangled somehow).  Both still pass if(bfs::is_regular_file).

Comment: @Roman R. The path may indeed be a clue.  It's of the format "D:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/Dir5/Dir6\Dir7".  I'll look into it and see if the slashes are causing a problem.  I did try running the service under the same credentials that I use to log on to the system, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah.  It was a bug in my "Condition2".  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

@Ennael:

don't forget that you need traversal permissions on all the parent folders/device nodes of the folder you are trying to access. I think Roman's suggestion would be first in line to eliminate the doubt (which, of course is really irrational: `Errno=13 == "permission denied"`).

You could start from there with a tools like

- cacls.exe

To do commandline ACL listing/editing

- [AccessEnum v1.32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332) to detect any changes in permissions across a filesystem tree (has a nifty option to only warn when permissions get more restricted or more permissive)

Comment: I gave "Everyone" full access to that directory and all its parent directories, including the drive itself.  I'm also running the service under my login (instead of LocalService).  AccessEnum and cacls confirm the permissions on the directory and AccessEnum still gives me the same result after rerunning the service.  I'll do some more reading/thinking about these tools.  Thanks.